# Telegram Passport. Where is use command "/setpublickey"?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I try produced my telegram bot with passport function.
https://core.telegram.org/passport

I produced my private key and public key. I don't understand where I must write the `/setpublickey` command.

In the section documentation, I can't find the command.
https://core.telegram.org/bots#botfather-commands

Can you explain to me? Where must I write `/setpublickey` command?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `/setpublickey` in the telegram chat of "BotFather" (it does not appear in the list of commands).
You will get a list with the bots that you have associated with your telegram account.
When selecting a bot it will tell you what you have to write in the terminal to generate the private and public key.

Private key:

```
openssl genrsa 2048 > private.key
```

Public key:

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -pubout
```

Now you just have to copy the public key of the terminal, from ----- BEGIN PUBLIC KEY ----- to ----- END PUBLIC KEY ----- (included) and paste it in the "BotFather" chat.